# Unit test with JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

Hi all i receive Nullpointer when trying to execute this unit test.I want to test e class which receive 3 parameters and returns a string. I think i need to make @Before or something else but it didn't works. Do you have suggestions...Thanks !

```
public class UrlConstructorTest {

    private UrlConstructor urlConstructor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        urlConstructor = new UrlConstructor();
    }

    public static final String TEST_UPDATE_MANIFEST_SR = "/packages/proxyId/test/test1/123/test3/test_test";

    @Test
    public void constructUpdateManifestSrInSasTokenTest() {
        String result = urlConstructor.composeDeviceRegistrationUrl("test","test123","test");
        System.out.println(result);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(TEST, result);
    }
}
```

[image]

UrlConstructor is define like this:

```
@Component
public class UrlConstructor {
```

And this is the method in this class:

```
 public String composeDUrl(String deviceId, String scopeId) {
    return String.format(Constants.socpe, tes, test);
  }
```

Comment: Test, you provided, passes for me without any NullPointer with simple UrlConstructor implementation always returning expected string.

Comment: I added that my UrlConstructor is with @Component. When i debug it i see that urlConstructor is comming null. Am i define it wrong?..

Comment: try using `@Autowired private UrlConstructor urlConstructor;`

Comment: post more of your UrlConstructor Class. Just because you instantiate your UrlConstructor does not mean that all the dependant beans are autowired. Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: btw `@Before` is JUnit 4, `@BeforeEach` is the equivalent for JUnit 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Junit5, you should be using `@BeforeEach`. Or you can get rid of that setUp method completely.

```
public class UrlConstructorTest {

       private final UrlConstructor urlConstructor = new UrlConstructor();

       public static final String TEST_SR = "/packages/proxyId/testID/product/testscope/testcomponent/coomponent_up";

      @Test
      public void constructTest() {
             String result = urlConstructor.composeDeviceRegistrationUrl("testID","coomponent_up","testscope");
             System.out.println(result);
             assertNotNull(result);
             assertEquals(TEST_SR, result);
      }
}
```